# How does one define dependent type with named arguments in Coq without issues in unification in the constructors?

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, proof-assistant

I want to defined a lenghted list but I like arguments with names at the top of the inductive definition. Whenever I try that I get unification errors with things I hoped worked and was forced to do a definition that obviously has bugs e.g. allows a list where everything is length 0 but has 1 element. How do I fix this?

```
  Inductive Vector {A : Type} (n : nat) : Type :=
    | vnil (* not quite right...*)
    | vcons (hd : A) (tail: Vector (n-1)).
  Check vnil 0.
  Check vcons 1 true (vnil 0).

  (* Inductive Vector' (n : nat) : Type :=
  | vnil': Vector' 0
  | vcons': A -> Vector' n -> Vector' (S n). *)

  Inductive Vector' {A: Type} : nat -> Type :=
  | vnil': Vector' 0
  | vcons': forall n : nat, A -> Vector' n -> Vector' (S n).
  Check vnil'.
  Check vcons' 0 true (vnil').

  Inductive Vector'' {A : Type} (n : nat) : Type :=
  | vnil'': Vector'' n (* seems weird, wants to unify with n, argh! *)
  | vcons'': A -> Vector'' (n-1) -> Vector'' n.
  Check vnil'' 0.
  Check vcons'' 1 true (vnil'' 0).
  (* Check vcons'' 0 true (vnil'' 0). *) (* it also worked! nooooo! hope the -1 did the trick but not *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Named arguments to the left of `:` (they are called parameters) are implicitly `forall`'d in each constructor and must appear as the same variable in the return type of each constructor. Arguments to the right (they are called indices) are not implicitly `forall`'d and may appear as anything. Part of the issue with your definitions is that `n` is already introduced by the time you're writing the type of each constructor, so you can't quite restrict it to be `Z` or `S m` at that point.

The idea is that parameters are supposed to be parameters to the whole inductive definition. `Vector A n` and `Vector B m` do not depend on each other; it would make sense to consider `Vector A` and `Vector B` to be different inductive definitions, and `Vector` as a family of inductives parameterized by a `Type`. On the other hand, `Vector A (S n)` refers to `Vector A n`; you cannot construct the type `Vector A (S n)` without first constructing `Vector A n`, so they should be considered parts of one inductive construction `Vector A : nat -> Type`.

This interpretation is not strictly enforced—you can poke a hole in it with `Inductive E (n : nat) : Set := | mk_E : E (S n) -> E n.`—but the rule about parameters vs. indices in constructor return types is enforced. It is the *intent of the design* of Coq that the "most natural" way to define `Vector` is

```
(* making A an implicit argument to Vector seems a bad idea... *)
Inductive Vector (A : Type) : nat -> Type :=
| vnil  : Vector A O
| vcons : forall n, A -> Vector A n -> Vector A (S n).
(* if you want to clean up vnil and vcons afterwards you can issue something like *)
Arguments vnil {A}.
Arguments vcons {A n}.
(* it would also work to define Vector with A implicit and then just use Arguments on Vector to make A explicit (it would leave n explicit in vcons), but that's just weird *)
```

If you want to clarify what the `nat` is doing, you could just leave a comment like

```
(* A [Vector A n] is a list of [n] elements of type [A]. *)
```

or

```
Inductive Vector (A : Type) : (* n *) nat -> Type :=
```

If you *really* want `Inductive Vector (A : Type) (n : nat) : Type`, then you have to resort to something like

```
Inductive Vector (A : Type) (n : nat) : Type :=
| vnil  (prf : n = O)
| vcons (m : nat) (prf : n = S m) (x : A) (xs : Vector A m).
```

Which makes everything messy.